# module 'csv' has no attribute 'writer'

Tags: python

I have a bit of code giving me trouble I was just trying to import my text file to a CSV file
but I m getting an error stating 
module CSV has no attribute 'writer'

Here is my code:

```
import csv 
f = open("Sales.txt")
x = f.readlines()
s = []`
print (f)
for i in x:
i = i.replace(","," ")
j = i.replace(" ",",")
s.append(j)
csvex =csv.write(open("Sample_CSV","w"),delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
csevx.writerow(s)
```

can someone figure this out what kind of error is this

Comment: Help us help you - please share the stacktrace

Comment: What is the back tick at line 4?

Comment: You need to reindent your code. Also, use `with` statements to open a file…

Answer (score 0):

It is not writer in your code change line:

```
csvex =csv.write(open("Sample_CSV","w"),delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

to:

```
csvex =csv.writer(open("Sample_CSV","w"),delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```